# Bootstrap pre element with overflow-x: auto has the width of the window instead of the parent

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, scrollbar, overflow

I have a [Bootstrap 4.3 pre](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/content/code/#code-blocks) as shown below.

A `<pre>` element has `overflow: auto;`, which means `overflow-x: auto;` and `overflow-y: auto;`. This produces a horisontal scroll bar when the content inside has more width than its parent.

But the parent elements width is not analysed correctly. If, for example, the `col-nav` to the left takes up 100px, then the `<pre>` is 125px too wide. Which makes the web page 125px too wide.

In other words, the width of the `<pre>` seems to be determined by the windows width.

Check it out in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/36Lpamvt/).

What am I doing wrong?

Ps. If I give the `<pre>` element a specific low width in px my web page stays within the width of the window, but not if I give it a low % width. I can't use something like `calc(100% - 125px);` either. But even if I could, I would not know what the width of `col-nav`.

```html
<body class="d-flex">
  <div class="col-nav base flex-fill mh-100">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="w-100 mh-100">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <pre>
        ...
      </pre>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that flexbox, by default, won't shrink something smaller than it can go.

Because your green text is one single word, and you didn't use `word-break:break-word;white-space:normal;` or something similar, the browser can't break the word into multiple lines, and therefore there's a minimum size that it can be shrunk.

If you want to shrink the flex item smaller than its minimum size, you'll need to use `min-width:0;` on the flex item.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gkvz6s3h/

Comment: Brilliant, thanks a lot, that solves my problem! But are there any downsides in this? From implementing it on my website it seems that everything else is intact. No unintended consequences. But maybe I haven't check everything.

Comment: No downsides, other than generally people **really** don't like horizontal scrollbars. Instead, they'd usually prefer to use `white-space:normal;word-break:break-word;`, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/r3ye10bv/1/

Comment: Point taken. Will think about that. In any case, big hugs from me to you. Will approve the answer tomorrow when the min. time has passed.